# Is it possible to get local variables through reflection?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a method with at least 50 local variables. I need to select a variable from a string value. Is it possible to access a local variable with C# reflection?

**Edit:**

```
void A()
{
    var a1 = List<MyClass>();
    var a2 = List<MyClass>();
    var a3 = List<MyClass>();
    var a4 = List<MyClass>();
    var a5 = List<MyClass>();
    ........................
    ........................
    ........................
    // I have a string value found at runtime. The possible values of it are a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,.... I need to select one
}
```

Comment: "I have a method with at least 50 local variables"... something not quite right there!

Comment: Can you give an example of your code? There's probably a better way to do what you want.

Comment: Fix your code, mate. We’re not going to tell you how to make it even worse.

Comment: You should use some kind of mapping data structure from string to list (Dictionary, anyone?)

Comment: Can't add this as an answer while the question is closed, but try replacing all these with a `Dictionary<string, List<MyClass>>`.

Comment: @Rawling That sounds like a bad suggestion, it works around a horrible design instead of fixing it. Oh, and a dictionary is unnecessary if those are indeed the variable names, an array would be enough (numeric indices).

Comment: @Konrad It's a bit harsh to declare needing several lists of objects to be a horrible design without knowing any context. And yes, an array would be enough (unless the zero-indexing is an issue).

Comment: Interestin! not a real question. What kind of questions you guys expect.

Comment: @NiklasB. I have included the code

Comment: @user: The question was closed before that happened

Comment: The code *doesn't even compile*.

Comment: @user960567 For the record, I closed it as “not constructive”. Yes, it’s a real question. But it’s not constructive: your code is broken, fix it first.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, but I have added the code for explaining the question. It is just give you the idea.

Comment: @user960567 The problem is that you have 50 variables in a single method.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, then it means unconstructive or not a real question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Real answer, no.

**After edited OP**: Definite no. The names are 'discarded' at compile time

You can get at the IL instructions, though (Method.Body).

Use Cecil Decompiler to 'guess' what would be variables (no names, though). However, it will be generally hard to distinguish (reused) temps from variables and all syntactic sugar is lost

Also: fix your code like the other comments say :)

Comment: Can you at runtime go from IL locals to their current values?

Comment: Wait. How did you sneak this in after the question was closed??

Comment: @sbi: I think you can post your unfinished answer until some minutes after the question gets closed if you don't refresh your browser.

Comment: @RMartinho: Not without using undocumented implementation details. Look at [stuff I did here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695827/how-to-get-current-value-of-eip-in-managed-code/5709842#5709842) for ways in which the implementation details _can_ be exploited. Great fun. Not recommended

Comment: Doesn't that work only semi-reliably on debug builds? I assume on release builds the locals can just be optimized somehow.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes True. It is all undocumented. Since we are talking about IL, JIT optimizations are out of scope (e.g. _enregister_-ing of valuetypes). Reference types cannot actually be elided due to garbage collection. However, local variables might not even actually be local (e.g. if they get closed-over in a lambda). It is all fairly involved and non-trivial