# How use a variable name to point different data types with the same name?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-structures, c#-3.0, logic

I have 2 List one stores the name of filterable columns(of type DropDown) and another store the values to load in those filterable columns.

```
 List<string> filterableFields = new List<string>() { "A_B", "C_D", "E_F" };
 List<string> AB, CD , EF;
```

Now at the run time I get the data from web service and I have written a function to to extract values for these filterable fields and store the values to 2nd List.

```
private void prepareListForFilterableColumns(XDocument records)
{
    foreach (var currentField in filterableFields)
    {
        var values = (from xml in records.Descendants(z + "row")
                      let val = (string)xml.Attribute("ows_" + currentField.Replace("_", "_x0020_"))
                      where val != ""
                      orderby val
                      select val 
                     ).Distinct();

        switch (currentField)
        {
            case "A_B": AB = values.ToList(); break;
            case "C_D": CD = values.ToList(); break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I was thinking that instead of hard coding the assignment in `swtich case` block, If I could just use the first List name "A_B" and replace "_" from it to point to my 2nd List and assign `values.ToList()` to it.

I understand that c# is a static language, So not sure if we can achieve this, but IF I can it will make my function generic.

Thanks a lot in advance for time and help.

Vishal

Comment: kinda related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118084/is-it-possible-to-get-local-variables-through-reflection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dictionary of lists of strings instead of 3 lists to store the values.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> val lists = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();
```

And make the keys of the dictionary equal to the filterables: "AB", "CD",..

then, instead of `AB` you would use `valLists["AB"]` and could then reference reach list based on a string key.

The other option would be to use reflection but that would be slower and unnecessarily a bit more complicated.