# How can i access the value of a local variable from within an expression tree

Tags: c#, reflection

By examining an expression tree i can get the value of a constant, instance field and property but not a local variable defined in a method.

Executing the following will output 1, 2, 3 (from the constant, instance field and property) then an exception as i don't know how to get the instance on which the FieldInfo is declared in order to call GetValue() for the local variable.

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Example
{
    class Program
    {
        private int _intField = 2;

        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().Run();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private void Run()
        {
            IntProp = 3;
            var intVariable = 4;
            Test(() => 1);
            Test(() => _intField);
            Test(() => IntProp);
            Test(() => intVariable);
        }

        public int IntProp { get; set; }

        void Test<T>(Expression<Func<T>> func)
        {
            var body = func.Body;

            if (body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(((ConstantExpression)body).Value);
            }
            else
            {
                var memberExpression = body as MemberExpression;

                var @object = memberExpression.Member.DeclaringType == GetType()
                    ? this
                    : null; //Can I do anything here? Instance of the method the variable is defined in?

                if (memberExpression.Member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(((FieldInfo)memberExpression.Member).GetValue(@object));
                }
                else if (memberExpression.Member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(((PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member).GetValue(@object));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You simply can't do this. The variable doesn't even exist unless the method is actually running.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get local variables through reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118084/is-it-possible-to-get-local-variables-through-reflection)

Comment: What are you trying to get? The parameter name? I'm a bit confused, but you always have the option to set a 'global' variable prior to invoking the method with whatever it is you need.

Comment: @MatthewWatson The question title is misleading. If you read his code, you see he has a _captured_ variable, inside lambda, and in that case the closure can easily exist after the method has stopped running. And surely you can read its value.

Comment: The question title is misleading - I wasn't sure what it was that I was asking for to be honest - was hoping the code would demonstrate what I was looking for. Will update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The local variable which has been captured by the lambda and included in the expression tree, will at that time really be a field on some compiler-generated class. This works on my version of .NET:

```
void Test<T>(Expression<Func<T>> func)
{
  var body = func.Body;

  if (body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(((ConstantExpression)body).Value);
  }
  else
  {
    var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)body;

    var @object = 
      ((ConstantExpression)(memberExpression.Expression)).Value; //HERE!

    if (memberExpression.Member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(((FieldInfo)memberExpression.Member).GetValue(@object));
    }
    else if (memberExpression.Member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(((PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member).GetValue(@object));
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, you can also "cheat":

```
void Test<T>(Expression<Func<T>> func)
{
  Console.WriteLine(func.Compile()());
}
```

Comment: Interesting! But if this is the answer, one has to wonder what the question is (i.e. I think the OP has posted an X-Y problem).

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes, I took the question as, "how can I change this assignment to `@object` to find the relevant target/instance?". However, it is not clear if he really needs the instance of the compiler-generated class (coming from the closure (local variable capture)).

Comment: The is exactly what I needed. That is exactly the question i should have asked.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot.

**Reflection does not extend to reading the values of method variable.**

It only handles the declaration metadata of variables. And even then, the compiler may have removed the variable you thought you declared. You allready can access to properties, fields.

Comment: If you read his code, you will see that what he has is an expression tree containing a _captured_ local variable. Such a thing will have been turned into a field on some compiler-generated class. Of course you should be able to read its value. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot because those variables are simply not available outside the method their scope.

Comment: The local variable in the asker's code has been captured in the lambda (closure), and as such is surely available. See my answer. The asker did not provide much explanation, so it was necessary to read his code.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't with reflection. But there are other methods to do so. As an example, I show you how to export a variable out of the functions' lexical scope.

Say you have a method like this:

```
private void f(int x)
{
    // your code here
}
```

You also have a piece of code like this:

```
int x_in_f;

f(3);
x_in_f = /* I want to have the value here */;
```

To get the value out of `f()` you must export a getter function. As `f()` returns `void`, you just could return the getter. In a general case (when `f()` has a non-void return type) you can leverage an `out` parameter. Here are both variants:

```
private Func<int> f(int x)
{
    // your code here

    return () => { return x; };
}
```

or through the `out` parameter:

```
private void f(int x, out Func<int> g)
{
    // your code here

    g = () => { return x; };
}
```

The code would then be:

```
int x_in_f;
Func<int> g;

g = f(3);

x_in_f = g(); // this will return the value of x as it was passed to f()
```

or through the `out` parameter invoke `f()` as follows:

```
f(3, out g);
```

At that point you can pass `g()` around to other functions:

```
private void h(Func<int> getx)
{
    // your code here
    int x = getx();
    // now you have the value of x inside the h() function
}
```

and the invocation with `h()`:

```
Func<int> g = f(3);

// ...

h(g);
```

I hope this helps or at least shows how to use closures to circumvent lexical scoping.

For the designers out there, this is the *Object Capability Model*. [This is a video](https://youtu.be/zKuFu19LgZA?t=41m58s) by Douglas Crockford on how to use it for security purposes in Javascript. It translates to C# and other purposes easily, as I've shown above.